# Blender knife tool not working as expected

Tags: 3d-view, error, knife-tool

I'm trying to create vertexes using the knife tool; the object in perspective mode is:

[image]

in plane after using knife:

[image]

A point is always created on the back edges:

[image]

It's incredibly frustrating to have to remove these stray vertices; is there a more fine grained way of using knife?

Comment: Hello :). The *Knife tool* is for cutting across polygons. And there doesn't seem to be a polygon under your knife. What exactly are you trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Hi! Create an edge between the vertexes in the second image (ideally it should be perpendicular to the base).

Comment: As @JachymMichal pointed out, you're trying to cut across a hole.  You need to fill that hole with a polygon first.  You can't cut across empty space.

Comment: @DaleCieslak Thanks!  Managed to use knife.